# Eclipse build automatically vs (Ant/Maven/Gradle)

Tags: java, eclipse, build-tools

What is the difference between Eclipse build automatically vs build tools (Ant/Maven/Gradle)?

Comment: One is internal to eclipse (and uses the eclipse compiler for java), and the other is external to Java and can use other compilers. Additionally, maven and gradle will **resolve** dependencies. Eclipse doesn't do that. But, Ant can do that with the addition of Apache Ivy.

Answer (score 1):

**Build automatically** means **incrementally compile Java code on save** by Eclipse own Java compiler, whereas a full Ant/Maven/Gradle build usually uses `javac` to compile the code and also does other things, e. g. creating of a JAR.

In Eclipse it's **not versus**, but an **interplay** of both:

1. You specify the dependencies in the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file
2. Maven/Gradle (embedded and triggered by Eclipse) resolves the dependencies and downloads the missing JARs into a local repository (Ant does not support this)
3. Eclipse incremental compiles the code (the required classpath is computed from the `pom.xml`/`build.gradle` file)

   - → Problems and quick fixes are displayed
   - → Code can be instantly executed
4. To create artifacts to deploy, run Ant/Maven/Gradle build

   - → Same artifacts independent where it has been built